# ORACLE APEX MULTIPLE DYNAMIC ACTIONS ON SINGLE BUTTON IN UNIVERSAL THEME

Tags: oracle-apex

I have executed an pl/sql query on my "run report button". It works fine. After the execution of the query I want it to be redirected to other page.The page to which it should be directed must be a modal page. How can I achieve this in Oracle Apex 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a branch with Type - Page or URL after processing with the "run report button" as server side condition and specify the modal page as target page.

**UPDATE**

You could follow the methods described [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4034653) and in [here](https://atulley.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/working-with-apex-5-dialogs/).

But here's another hack that's relatively simpler to implement over those 2 approaches.

- Create a 'REDIRECT_TO_MODAL' button and set the server side condition to 'Never'
- Create a After processing branch with Type - Page or URL target and specify the modal page as target and select 'REDIRECT_TO_MODAL' as the button in server side condition.
- To the already defined dynamic action, add another true action after the execution of PL/SQL process and make it 'Execute Javascript' with the following code:
  -`apex.submit({ request:"REDIRECT_TO_MODAL",showWait:false});`

Also, make sure on the modal page, both Page Mode and Dialog Template are set to Modal Dialog.

Comment: I tried it but the page is not being redirected...Don't know what I am missing out!!

Comment: Don't think you can branch to modal page. It will just branch back to submitted page. You can do a few things. Set a branch back to this page and set some request value that you can check for to then open the modal when the page refreshes. You can change the process so it runs as a Dynamic Action instead of submitting the page. You could let the button call the modal page by making the button link directly to that page, set the linked page as Modal, and then inside the modal page let it do the query.

Comment: I apologize I did not pay attention to the title while I was answering the question before, didn't realize you're using dynamic action and thought it was submit on page for the button. I have now updated the answer, please check.